# c programming quick sort, bubble sort demo with pointers

Tags: c, loops, sorting, pointers, exit

Sorry ahead of time this code will be kinda of long as the nature of the function, however i've implemented a demo function to test the differences in speed with bubble sort and quick sort perfectly fine output(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzDAD.jpg) the menu function works fine i wont include that part

i haven't included the demo function if you guys want to i can include it

however when i implement the same functions with pointers i keep getting a strange output(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENydz.jpg) where i will have variable amount of tests returned for the pointers. Below i've place the relevant code, any help at all would be very appreciated.

I do have a main function and some others not included because they work fine and i dont believe them to be the problem, my intuition says that the problem lies in the loops of the Bubble_mode_p function or the quicksort_p function, the program does compile in cygwin using the command

```
gcc -o calc calc.c -std=c99 -lm
```

Here is the source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#define KEY "Enter the calculator operation you want to do: "
#define enter_option() printf("%s", KEY)
//Timing functions are below**********************************************************************
#define timing_start() start = clock();     
#define timing_end(f) msec = (double)(clock()-start) * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC; \
    printf("Calling "#f " takes %10.2f microseconds!\n", msec);

void Quick_mode_p();
int* quicksort_p(int *left, int *right, int *pivot);
void Bubble_mode_p(int *ptr,int s);
void swap(int *a, int *b);

void Quick_mode_p() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int t1,t2,t_tot;

    printf("\n");
    printf("***************    Report of performance comparision    ***************\n"); 
    printf("\n");       
    printf("             quicksort       bubblesort      (in microseconds)\n"); 
    int end=0;
    do {
        int start=0,top=0;
        end+=500;
        int a[end],b[end];
        int *p=&a[0],*q=&a[end],*k=&a[0];
        int *f=&b[0];
        printf("N=%d:   ",end);
        for (int j=0;j<end;j++){
            a[j]=rand()%((2*end)+1)-end;
            if(a[j]<start)
                start=a[j];
            else if (a[j]>top)
                top=a[j];
        }
        for(int i=0;i<end;i++){
            b[i]=a[i];
        }

        t1=clock();
        quicksort_p(p,q,k);   
        t2=clock();
        t_tot= (double)(t2-t1)*1000000/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        printf("\t%7.1d\t", t_tot);
        t1=clock();
        Bubble_mode_p( f,end);
        t2=clock();
        t_tot= (double)(t2-t1)*1000000/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        printf("\t%7.1d\t", t_tot);

        printf("      array in range: [%d,%d]\n",start ,top ); 
        printf("\n");       
    } while (end!=5000); 
    clean_input();

}

int *quicksort_p(int *left, int *right, int *pivot) {
    int *i, *q;
    q = right;
    i = left ;
    int p = *pivot;

    while (q > pivot) {
        while ( p < *i )
            pivot++;
        while ( *q > *i )
            q--;
        if ( q > pivot ) {
            swap(pivot,q);
        }
    }
    swap(left, q);
    return q ;
}

void Bubble_mode_p(int *ptr,int s) {
    int i,j;
    int temp;
    for (i=1;i<s;i++) {
        for (j=0;j<s-i;j++) {
            if (*(ptr+j)>*(ptr+j+1)) {
                temp=*(ptr+j);
                *(ptr+j)=*(ptr+j+1);
                *(ptr+j+1)=temp;
            }
        }

    }
}

void swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int c = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = c;
}
```

Comment: Debugger...................

Comment: my noviceness is going to show here ive never used debugger before, can you  point me in a direction

Comment: You `quicksort` gets stuck in `while (p < *i)` while `pivot++` walks off the end of your stack. For debug, use `gcc -o calc calc.c -std=c99 -g`, then `gdb ./calc` and set a break point on the entry of `main` with `break main`, then use `s` to step though your code.

Comment: THANK YOU DAVID. I LOVE YOU DAMMIT

Comment: 'ive never used debugger before' stop developing software until you know how to use such tools.  Without debugging skills, you cannot program computers beyond 'Hello World!' level and should not be trying.